How to make a Gsheet 2.1 gestal compatible?
i got this modified gsheet 2.1 that i want to convert to work under gestalt rules, multiclass and xp base https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HZeFpLm3ZSAn-U4P5nEcei1mgIYCZYaIyD1RKh9ho34/edit?gid=359784640#gid=359784640
i tried to make the lv shown to be the average of both classes, but it realy is not made for multclass, i would greatly appreciate the help
